# Oracle XE configuring for benchmark

Tags: database, oracle, benchmarking, oracle-xe, hammerdb

Have a good day.

The task is to configure Oracle XE for performance benchmark using HammerDB. Well, the HammerDB script for creating schema and driver script are both done. But trying to create schema or run a benchmark Oracle XE returns me different errors.

Error can be:

1. KPEDBG_HDL_PUSH_FCPTRMAX;
2. KPEDBG_HDL_POP_FCPTR;
3. KPEDBG-...TLSORA-24550 and smth else;
4. No errors sometimes.

Well, previously I've created tablespaces for my future benchmark user:

- alter session set container=XEPDB1 (that's the name of pluggable database);
- create tablespace tpcctab datafile 'tpcctab.dat' size 10G autoextend on;
- create temporary tablespace tpcctemp tempfile 'tpcctemp.dat' size 5G autoextend on;

Well, those statements are done correct and HammerDB tpcc user creates correct. Then Oracle XE returns me one of errors above.

HammerDB creating schema script: [image: 1]

HammerDB benchmark script:

[image: 2]

Additionally I've added in initXE.ora:

```
mts_dispatchers="(address=(partial=true)(protocol=tcp)(host=192.168.192.11.1)(port=1521))(dispatchers=8)"
```

Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Any ideas how to resolve? By the way, we can not move to Enterprise edition.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### KPEDBG_HDL_PUSH_FCPTRMAX;

You have data structures in your Database which is protected. If you have (i. e. in a Benchmark) concurrent accesses by multiple threads in this structure this failure will be raised. You can lower down the threads in the benchmark. Push means you will ad something in the stack.

### KPEDBG_HDL_POP_FCPTR

Looks similar to me. I will guess, this failure will be raised if you have concurrent accesses by multiple threads.
Pop means you will remove something in the stack.

2 different failures same cause: multiple threads in a protected data structure.

### KPEDBG_POP_KGPPTR_TLSORA-24550

That is an official issue in Oracle. You could search for ora-24550. An update should help to solve this problem.

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/889345/ora-24550-signal-received-unhandled-exception-code-e0434f4d-flags-1

Comment: Of course, there is a multithreaded benchmark, and I understand that there is the concurrent access attempt - but I do not very understand how to come over it. About the third error message - I will try to reproduce that.... it is not very frequent message

Comment: You had reached the maximum concurrent access attempt for your data structure. You are making a benchmark test and you reached the limits. You could try to reduce the virtual users, reduce the clients per virtual user or raise the client login delay.  Your configuration on this machine kills your DMS.

Comment: hammerdb>KPEDBG_POP_KGPPTR_TLSORA-24550: signal received: Unhandled exception: Code=ebf00baa Flags=0

Comment: How can I set the limits? Or should I understand 'Up to 2 CPU threads' limitation as Up to 2 virtual users?

Comment: For that you could have a look at the official doc from hammerdb: https://www.hammerdb.com/docs/ch04s09.html

Comment: I meant how can I set the limits in OracleXE, not in HammerDB

Comment: You couldn't do that. OracleXE limits itself automatically. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/oracle-database-xe-cpu-limitations.html

Comment: Summing up, I should adjust the test parameters to meet the product  limitations, shouldn't I?

Comment: Yes. Or Upgrade your DMS or change your DMS.

Comment: you say I've reached  the maximum concurrent access attempt for data structure - and you say 2 different failures same cause: multiple threads in a protected data structure. Could you tell me, please, can I make data structures unprotected? Or may it be another way?

Comment: There is a reason for protecting data structure. Imagine you have an excel sheet. Imagine more than one is working with it. Everyone save their files in exact the same time. Which one should be saved? Your question now are different to the original post. Did this Answer had helped you for your original question?

Comment: Thank you for your help) It definitely is.